# Does F# have a help function that converts the method signature like this?

Tags: f#

To simplify the question, if there is a method that has no overloading, and its signiture is: `Func<int, int, int, int>`, does F# have any helper function to get `(fun (a, b, c) -> myFun(a, b, c))` which is of signiture `Func<int * int * int, int>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In other functional languages, this is usually called "un-currying", but F# does not include this in the core library. You can define the function quite easily yourself:

```
let uncurry3 f = (fun (a,b,c) -> f a b c)
```

Unfortunately, this won't work for *any* number of arguments - you need to define `uncurryX` for each number of arguments that you would like to use.

In practice, I would probably not do this though. It can lead to point-free code that is hard to read and debug. Sometimes, a bit more verbosity is useful :-) and if you end up applying this to a certain function too often, it is a good sign that perhaps it should have been defined in the other style.

BTW: The answer is assuming that you use `Func` to refer to ordinary F# functions. If you were referring to the .NET `Func` delegate (rather than functions), then you could write:

```
let uncurry3 (f:Func<_, _, _, _>) = 
  System.Func<_, _>(fun (a,b,c) -> f.Invoke(a, b, c))
```